# Swift - получить имя выбранного изображения

Tags: swift

Как можно получить имя картинки после выбора?

```
как бы я не пробовал он выдает: 

Optional("<UIImage: 0x7fa61944c3d0>")
```

Код:

```
@IBAction func tappedBgButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.SavedPhotosAlbum)
    {
        print("chooseImage Button: ")

        imagePicked = 2

        print(imagePicked)

        self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

@IBAction func tappedAvatarButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.SavedPhotosAlbum)
    {
        print("chooseImage Button: ")

        imagePicked = 1

        print(imagePicked)

        self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage

    if imagePicked == 1 {
        userAva.image = pickedImage

    } else if imagePicked == 2 {
        userBG.image = pickedImage
    }
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Вашей 3й функции добавьте:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    if let pickedImageURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? NSURL {
        ALAssetsLibrary().assetForURL(pickedImageURL , resultBlock: { asset in
           let imageName = asset.defaultRepresentation().filename()
           //imageName получено, используйте в своих целях
           }, failureBlock: nil)
       }
    }
    ...
}
```

или

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    if let pickedImageURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? NSURL {
        let result = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs([pickedImageURL], options: nil)
        let imageName = result.firstObject?.filename ?? ""
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: не тот не другой вариант не работает пишет Cannot convert value of type 'UIImage?' to expected element type 'NSURL'

Comment: @Malyshev не досмотрел, подправил, обновил ответ

Comment: спасибо все получилось!